# Wicket and AJAX : Upload file to server and show it on page

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

My web application is running on tomcat6 and I'm using **Wicket** to develop it.
What I'm trying to do is to upload image file to the server and display it on web page as soon as it will be uploaded. I'm uploading file via AJAX as described [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/upload?1). The file is uploaded it is stored on disk in `/home/mysuser/` path. When the file is uploaded, I'm executing JavaScript in order to load that file in to HTML object with:

Wicket code:

```
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
{
    target.appendJavaScript("loadOriginalImage(\""+
              (UPLOAD_FOLDER + TMP_FILE_NAME1)+"\")");
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
function loadOriginalImage(image_path){
   var curImg = new Image();
   curImg.src = "file://"+image_path;
   curImg.onload = function(){
      imgHolder.appendChild(this);   
   }
}
```

The file is uploaded well, but when the JavaScript is executed, the next error appears:

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

Then I've tried to remove `"file://"` from JavaScript code, as I've found that file is read from client's local folder and not from server's. But this time I've got next error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/home/myuser/originalImg.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

So I have two questions:

**1.** How I specify in JavaScript the correct path of uploaded file?

**2.** Is my strategy is correct to load image to web page after uploading it to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mount Resource to `"home/myuser/${name}"`, read [this](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/) acticle for details.

You can adjust caching with the following code (no caching in the example):

```
@Override
protected void setResponseHeaders(ResourceResponse data, Attributes attributes) {
    data.setCacheDuration(Duration.NONE);
    super.setResponseHeaders(data, attributes);
}
```

To allow certain extensions check these resources:

- [SecurePackageResourceGuard](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/SecurePackageResourceGuard.html) JavaDoc.
- [An example of usage.](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/resourceaggregation/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.resourcedecoration.HomePage&source=ResourceDecorationApplication.java)

Comment: It creates url to image well, but returns the same 404 error. How can I check if the resource is mapped well?

Comment: Is your Resource class have been called? Put a breakpoint to check this. If you share more code it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, it is called. I've solved the problem. I do not know why in function `getImageAsBytes()`, from the article you gave, was impossible to write image with `.jpg` extension. When I've changed extension to `.jpeg` it worked! Another problem that I had it was a browser cache! Now I need to find how to deactivate cache only for this image. Thank you for help!

Comment: Just to be sure...I can't load two resources simultaneously, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to consider with your approach:

- escaping file names
- the webserver (tomcat/wicket in this case) most likely can not serve files from some arbitrary directory

You should implement a Resource that streams the images back and mount this Resource as Alexey  has pointed out.

make sure, that you only serve image files, Make sure that you disable directory traversal, otherwise someone will figure out how to read any file from the file system.