# Image resources in css files

Tags: wicket

There is a library containing package x.y.z.images where are stored some useful images. My application contains this library in WEB-INF/lib as usual.

I would like to know (if it's possible at all) what url to put in my css files, to get those images load appropriately.

I have found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641739/image-referencing-in-css-with-wicket) here, where they use shared resource. But for me it's unacceptable to register all images one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16271204/1065759) answer. In the blog post I mentioned check ImageResource. 
All you need is to implement getImageAsBytes method.

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I use Wicket 1.4.

Comment: I didn't work with wicket 1.4... but at least DynamicImageResource is present in the API (http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/image/resource/DynamicImageResource.html). Try to follow the article if it doesn't help I'll check alternatives later...

Comment: DynamicImageResource in wicket 1.4 has getImageData() instead of getImageData(Attributes attributes) method. So I don't have access to the attributes.

Comment: ok, try this RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getParameter(parameterName);

Comment: Looking at the end of the article, there is generated the url as follows: getRequestCycle().urlFor(imagesResourceReference, imageParameters); but I need the url in my static css file

Comment: if you mount it with say `/resources/img/${name}` you can use `/resources/img/my-image.png` in your css

Comment: it would be easy if you deploy your app as a ROOT application, otherwise you need specify context...

Comment: I recommend you to use relative path in css to avoid this

Comment: When I use relative path in css, then the image is expected to be relative to the css itself, doesn't it? Then I can't point to the images in library package structure, right?

Comment: let's say you have css:
 /resources/style/all.css
and Resource for retrieving images:
 /resources/img/${name}


In css you can use code like this:
  `background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);`
   
or

  `background-image: url(../img/x.y.z.img1.jpg);`

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this is unachievable for me. I just don't get it at all. I will duplicate all those images from the library to the application.